# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at line 13:1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**while working on code ran into some errors on line 13 when the value is undefined and is reading as 0 please how can I solve this**

the error message

> homepage.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const danceClass = useSelector((state) => state.class);
  const { classes } = danceClass;

  const [dance, setDance] = useState(
    classes[0] ? classes[0].slice(0, 3) : [],
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use fallbacks for possibly undefined values for instance

```js
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const danceClass = useSelector((state) => state?.class ?? {});
  const { classes = [] } = danceClass;

  const [dance, setDance] = useState(
    classes[0]?.slice(0, 3) ?? [],
  );
```

Like that, you are going to check whather or not state.class is a nullish value, if it's nullish, with the use of [nullish coaleascing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) you are going to assign an empty object.

Then, when destructuring for classes, if danceClass is an empty object without the property classes, what you're getting is a variable classes initialized as an empty array.

Then again, with the use of chaining operator in classes[0]?.slice(0, 3) you're checking if the first element is nullish, (through the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) if this is your're going to set the dance variable as an empty array again with the use of [nullish coaleascing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Answer (score 1):

If your `danceClass` object doesn't have a `classes` property, then `classes` will be `undefined` and `classes[0]` will produce the error you're seeing.

Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead

```js
const [dance, setDance] = useState(classes?.[0]?.slice(0, 3) ?? []);
```

The above will also work if `classes` is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `classes` is `undefined`. You should check like

```
classes ? classes[0]?.slice(0,3) : []
```

Comment: i works but generates a new error

Comment: I editted the answer. What's the error?